# Development tools infected?

Tags: android, eclipse, antivirus, trojan

My antivirus program (CA Anti-Virus) just started reporting the existence of "AndroidOS/SMSTroj.D!generic" in a few of the .dex files generated for my Android projects in Eclipse. (I'm *not* writing malware!)

Has anyone else seen anything similar?

Is my development environment infected somehow, or is this a false positive? How can I verify and, if it's real, disinfect my system?

I haven't found any info about this trojan (the CA site reports no info). Does anyone have pointers to info about this (in particular about disinfecting the development environment)?

Comment: I would suggest contacting security@android.com. I suppose it's conceivable that some other virus/malware infected your development environment, though that would seem to break ground on a couple of fronts.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Good suggestion; I'll do that. Meanwhile, I have some more info: none of Microsoft Security Essentials, Norton Anti-Virus or Avast are complaining about these particular files. For now, I'm treating this as a false positive and I'll contact CA as well. The timing is suspicious, though; all the files were produced after updating to the latest Android tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacting CA does seem like a good idea, but it might also be interesting to create a blank/hello world app and clean/rebuild the dex files a few times and see if anything picks up. Somehow I doubt a virus would try to parse your program and see what it's doing (other than perhaps permissions of the manifest, I guess you could copy over those from your "infected" project) so a build of any dex I would think should give you the same results. I suspect it's a false positive too. If it comes through clean you can slowly add a few classes at a time from your "infected" project and narrow it down that way.

Comment: After a lot of experimenting along these lines, I agree that this is a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its a TROJAN. 
Have a look here.

https://www.virustotal.com/file/dcf44f7262682ec2274829e6a14dfde470ca60dc1fbb2b76ff1053230ae305c2/analysis/1323302988/

Comment: That web page doesn't do much more than list the names of known malware. I already know that it's the _name_ of a trojan. The question is whether this is for real or a false positive.